# How do I extend the expiration date on firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, facebook-authentication, firebase-authentication

Using firebase, I can log in a user using facebook as a the provider, and keep the user logged in - based on the number of days I set for the database setting. I have it set to 60 days.

My question is, how to I extend the expiration?

Is it done on the facebook side, or on the firebase side?

On the facebook side, I see
From here - https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html - I can get

facebook.accessToken    The Facebook OAuth 2.0 access token granted by Facebook during user authentication.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending

That looks like I will get a new facebook access token.

For the firebase side, it looks like I might need to do something with, Custom Auth to extend the user session?

Has someone done this before?

Its similar to this question - [Firebase re-authentication required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527600/firebase-re-authentication-required) - but the asker is interested in detecting expiration, and for this question I'm only interested in refreshing the token.